# Math.random() not outputting correct random number with inline $Emit

Tags: javascript, html, function, vue.js, emit

I am trying to understand how $emit event works in vue so following this Guide: https://learnvue.co/tutorials/vue-emit-guide,
I tried to do in similar way but with vue2 js and everytime I click the button its gives me rounded number but not random number as the Guide link.

I want to know where I am doing wrong and why in the guide line they are passing i variable
like this:

> <ChildComponent @add="(i) => count += i" />

My child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="inline-emit">
    <h1 class="mesg-text">{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>We can send data up from Child.vue</p>

    <button class="btn" @click="$emit('add', Math.random())">
      Add Math.random()
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InlineEmitEventChild",
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      default: "Example of an inline Emit",
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

my App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Emitting and Listening to Events</h1>
    <InlineEmitEventChild @add="add(10)" />
    <p class="count-text">
      Count: <strong>{{ count }}</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InlineEmitEventChild from "./components/InlineEmitEventChild.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    InlineEmitEventChild,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    add(i) {
      this.count += i;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Getting always rounded number :

[image]

**Should be as below:**

[image]

Comment: You hardcoded an increment to be `10` and ignore event value. Should be `@add="add"` or `@add="add($event)"` if you expect it to be passed

Answer (score 0):

At your parent component you have hardcoded value,

```
<InlineEmitEventChild @add="add(10)" />
```

Change it to

```
<InlineEmitEventChild @add="add" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For test the code you can go here >>> [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/emittest-t2nqtb?file=/src/components/RandomWorld.vue) just click the **Add Math Random** to get the random number.

child component

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <button @click="addRandom">Add Math Random</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "RandomWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      Num1: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addRandom() {
      this.Num1 = Math.random(this.Num1);
      console.log(this.Num1);
      this.$emit("getrandom", this.Num1);
      //console.log(this.Num1);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

parent component

```
<template>
   <Childcomponent @getrandom="displayRandom($event)"/>
</template>
<script>
import Childcomponentvue from "./childcomponents.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Childcomponent: Childcomponentvue,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Random:0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    displayRandom(e){
      console.log(e);
      this.Random = e;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```